# Write a function to find dataset matches, merge two columns in the same position in each dataframe and export to .csv

Tags: r

I have some datasets in my Global Enviroment that follow the same pattern: IV.a, MO.a, ME.a, DV.a, (Pattern 1), IV.a.a, MO.a.a, ME.a.a, DV.a.a. (Pattern 2). For each of those dataframes that follow the same pattern, I would like to write a function that combines the 2nd and 3rd column into one data frame, name the dataframe with everything after the first dot (e.g. "a", "a.a") and export it. I know that I can use the command `cbind.na` from the package `qpcR` to combine columns with different numbers of observations. I will have 50+ dataframes that is why I am exploring if there is an option to automate this.

```
IV.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",50), IV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = T), IV.z = seq(1:50))
MO.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",28), MO.y = sample(letters[1:7], 28, replace = T), MO.z = seq(1:28))
ME.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",10), ME.y = sample(letters[1:10], 10, replace = T), ME.z = seq(1:10))
DV.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",100), DV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = T), DV.z = seq(1:100))

IV.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",50), IV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = T), IV.z = seq(1:50))
MO.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",28), MO.y = sample(letters[1:7], 28, replace = T), MO.z = seq(1:28))
ME.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",10), ME.y = sample(letters[1:10], 10, replace = T), ME.z = seq(1:10))
DV.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",100), DV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = T), DV.z = seq(1:100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer depends on whether or not you can discern a unique regex for each of your 'patterns', e.g. for "IV.a" you could use `"^..\\.a$"` (^ = at the beginning of the string, .. = match any two letters, \\.a = match a fullstop (escaped) followed by the letter 'a', $ = followed by the end of the string).

If your 'patterns' in your actual data are more complicated this may cause issues. Regardless, here is a potential solution:

```r
IV.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",50), IV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = T), IV.z = seq(1:50))
MO.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",28), MO.y = sample(letters[1:7], 28, replace = T), MO.z = seq(1:28))
ME.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",10), ME.y = sample(letters[1:10], 10, replace = T), ME.z = seq(1:10))
DV.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",100), DV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = T), DV.z = seq(1:100))

IV.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",50), IV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace = T), IV.z = seq(1:50))
MO.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",28), MO.y = sample(letters[1:7], 28, replace = T), MO.z = seq(1:28))
ME.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",10), ME.y = sample(letters[1:10], 10, replace = T), ME.z = seq(1:10))
DV.a.a <- data.frame(x = rep("a",100), DV.y = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = T), DV.z = seq(1:100))

regexes <- c("^..\\.a$", "^..\\.a\\.a$")
for (reg in regexes){
  dflist <- mget(ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern = reg), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  dflist_specific_cols <- lapply(dflist, "[", 2:3)
  mx <- max(sapply(dflist_specific_cols, nrow))
  new_df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(dflist_specific_cols, function(x) {rbind(x, x[seq_len(mx) > nrow(x),, drop = FALSE])}))
  new_name <- gsub("^..\\...|\\\\|.$", "", reg)
  write.csv(x = new_df, file = paste(new_name, ".csv", sep = ""),
            quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

This saves two csv files to your working directory ("a.csv" and "a.a.csv").

There is very likely better solutions to this problem, but at least this is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Thank you @jared_mamrot. I have a follow up question: Is it possible to save all datasets in one excel file, saving each dataset in a separate sheet?

Comment: For exampe using the package `openxlsx`.

Comment: Yes, you could create a list of dataframes then save the list as a workbook. This tutorial explains how: https://newbedev.com/use-r-and-openxlsx-to-output-a-list-of-dataframes-as-worksheets-in-a-single-excel-file